# capybara does not find elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

After an upgrade from rails 3 to rails 4, my feature specs using capybara and capybara webkit fail.
Capybara suddenly fails to find elements, although they are within page.html or page.body.

Some info:

- A page.html.index('id="element"') returns a number while page.all('#element') (or any other finder method) does not. However this is not true for all elements, some are found.

  ```
  page.body.index('id="assessment_title"')=> 55688  
  page.all("#assessment_title") => []
  ```
- I have tried several versions of the capabara gem.
- A JQuery selector on the rendered page (via save_and_open_page) also finds the element.
- I am using rspec 3, but had it working with this version before the rails upgrade

I am not sure where to go from here anymore. Any help on next steps would be very appreciated?

Thanks,
migo

Comment: Can you update your question to include an example of what you're trying to do with these values? It's possible that you just need to do something else to test whatever it was that you were testing.

Comment: Did you change capybara versions in the process?

Comment: Is the element visible?

Comment: Yes I have tried different capybara version (2.1 .. 2.3).
The element is visisble.
In specific I am trying to do a `fill_in 'assessment_title', :with => @assessment.title`. `fill_in <label of element>, :with => @assessment.title` doesnt work either. 
What troubles me is that finders on some elements work, but others cannot be found. I wonder whether something in the page dom, that with the whole change to rails 4 has changed, breaks the parser? I could do a detailed diff of the two rendered pages..